# HTTP Logging for Cloud Functions to see request information?

Tags: node.js, firebase, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am looking to see if there is a way to add logging to Cloud Functions so I can could see request information in my logs.

I have my Cloud Functions app setup for example like this:

```
const app: express.Application = express();

// Logger Middleware
app.use(morgan("dev"));

app.use(cors({origin: true}));

// Routes
app.get("/api", async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  console.log("Getting all users..3.");
  const users = await User.getAllUsers();
  return res.json(users);
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

When I make a http request to my functions endpoint the logs just show that the us-central-app being started "function execution" and then print my console.log in the endpoint handler.

However I am trying to see if I could get some logging, similar to how Morgan works but it doesn't format well with Cloud Functions logging.

Is there a better way for me to see which endpoint got hit, request information etc with the functions logger?

[image]

Comment: You may refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging). Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to [Writing structured logs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#writing_structured_logs).

> The provided snippet shows how to write structured log entries. It also shows how to correlate log messages with the corresponding request log.